# Are there docblox in R?

Tags: r, rstudio

When writing PHP in Netbeans, as long as I provide my functions and classes with "docblox", Netbeans will show what parameters a function expects, what it will return, and a short description whenever I go to call it somewhere else. There is also the benefit of using it for automatically generated API documentation with a tool such as PHPDocumentor2. Is there any kind of equivalent in R? Currently I'm developing in RStudio.

Example of a docblox in PHP:

```
/**
 * This is the description of some function
 *
 * @param string $foo A foo string
 * @return string Foo string in all caps
 */
 function cap_foo($foo) { return strtoupper($foo); }
```

Answer (score 2):

Is docblox the commented part? If so, check [roxygen2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/index.html)

Comment: Yes, the commented part is the docblox